# Renaming a folder and not losing the link between the branch and the trunk

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I had two working copies: of a trunk and of a branch:

- trunk -> App 1.0
- branches -> 1.2 -> App 1.0

I needed to rename `App 1.0` to `Application` ("1.0" being an archaism from the days where versioning was done "manually" and SVN was underused to put it mildly; I'm trying to set it right now, although I haven't had much experience with source control).

I did `TortoiseSVN -> Rename` on my `1.2\App 1.0` and `trunk\App 1.0` local disk folders (working copies), and I renamed the folders in the repository as well (via the `Repo-browser`).

And yet code file `abc.cs` in the 1.2 branch still "thinks" that its base is the old file: `App 1.0/abc.cs`.

`Diff with previous version` gives me an error (*"Subversion reported an error: Unable to find repository location for 1.2\App 1.0\abc.cs in revision 604"*).

See the revision graph for this file:

[image]

(I edited out the actual name of the application for reasons easy to understand.)

Propagating trunk modifications by merging them into the branch is now a bit troublesome.

What's more, my collegue still has an `App 1.0` working copy (hasn't comitted nor updated it yet), so I'm somewhat afraid that we're about to mess things up, and I'm not sure how to go on from here.

**The question is:** where did I do wrong, and how do I fix that (both for me as well as my collegue)?

I guess that renaming both folders independently was the mistake that broke history tracing (no direct connection between 637 and 639 on the picture now, while that's what I would need); I'm just not sure what I should have done instead, and neither how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by renaming both the working copy and the repo folder without communicating either change (as you thought).

As per the thread [here](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/41094-Broke-history-path-by-independently-renaming-folders-in-the-trunk-and-in-the-branch), you could have renamed the repo folder, then updated the working copy, or used the command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check out a fresh working copy - it may be possible that everything is OK in the repository...